# Reading a CSV and writing the exact file back with one column changed

Tags: python

I'm looking to read a CSV file and make some calculations to the data in there (that part I have done).
After that I need to write all the data into a new file **Exactly** the way it is in the original with the exception of one column which will be changed to the result of the calculations.

I can't show the actual code (confidentiality issues) but here is an example of the code.

```
headings = ["losts", "of", "headings"]
with open("read_file.csv", mode="r") as read,\
    open("write.csv", mode='w') as write:
    reader = csv.DictReader(read, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(write, fieldnames=headings)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerows()
```

At this stage I am just trying to return the same CSV in "write" as I have in "read"

I haven't used CSV much so not sure if I'm going about it the wrong way, also understand that this example is super simple but I can't seem to get my head around the logic of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close!

```py
headings = ["losts", "of", "headings"]
with open("read_file.csv", mode="r") as read, open("write.csv", mode='w') as write:
    reader = csv.DictReader(read, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(write, fieldnames=headings)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        # do processing here to change the values in that one column
        processed_row = some_function(row)
        writer.writerow(processed_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me get a little closer to the goal, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd
csv_file = pd.read_csv('read_file.csv')
# do_something_and_add_a_column_here()
csv_file.to_csv('write_file.csv')
```

Comment: I cant use pandas, this utility has to be run on the work server, and they will not install Py packages to the server for this, it has to be done in the native Python libraries